# oracle delete selected objects from schema

Tags: oracle

I want to delete objects from schema and I have stored all the objects those should not be deleted in a table, all other objects which are not in the table should be deleted. I have following code which is not working can some one help me here. I have searched the net there is only one thing "DELETE ALL OBJECT" which is not relevant to my case.

```
DECLARE
    stringa VARCHAR2(100);
    stringb VARCHAR2(1000) := '';
    CURSOR cur IS
      SELECT *
      FROM   user_objects;
BEGIN
    FOR c IN cur LOOP
        BEGIN
            stringa := '';

            BEGIN
                SELECT tab_name
                INTO   stringb
                FROM   zretain_list;

                IF c.object_type = 'VIEW' THEN
                  stringa := 'drop view '
                             || c.object_name;

                  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stringa;
                ELSIF c.object_type = 'TABLE'
                      AND c.object_name != stringb THEN
                  stringa := 'drop table  "'
                             || c.object_name
                             || '" cascade constraints';

                  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stringa;
                ELSIF c.object_type = 'SEQUENCE' THEN
                  stringa := 'drop sequence '
                             || c.object_name;

                  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stringa;
                ELSIF c.object_type = 'PACKAGE' THEN
                  stringa := 'drop package '
                             || c.object_name;

                  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stringa;
                ELSIF c.object_type = 'TRIGGER' THEN
                  stringa := 'drop trigger '
                             || c.object_name;

                  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stringa;
                ELSIF c.object_type = 'PROCEDURE' THEN
                  stringa := 'drop procedure '
                             || c.object_name;

                  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stringa;
                ELSIF c.object_type = 'FUNCTION' THEN
                  stringa := 'drop function '
                             || c.object_name;

                  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stringa;
                ELSIF c.object_type = 'SYNONYM' THEN
                  stringa := 'drop synonym '
                             || c.object_name;

                  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stringa;
                ELSIF c.object_type = 'INDEX' THEN
                  stringa := 'drop index '
                             || c.object_name;

                  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stringa;
                ELSIF c.object_type = 'PACKAGE BODY' THEN
                  stringa := 'drop PACKAGE BODY '
                             || c.object_name;

                  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stringa;
                ELSIF c.object_type = 'DATABASE LINK' THEN
                  stringa := 'drop database link '
                             || c.object_name;

                  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stringa;
                END IF;
            EXCEPTION
                WHEN OTHERS THEN
                  NULL;
            -- PURGE recyclebin
            END;
        END;
    END LOOP;
END;

/
```

Comment: One problem you have here is that dropping some object types will automatically cascade the drop to other types. For example, dropping a table will drop triggers, materialised view logs, and indexes. What kind of objects do you need to deal with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with something like

```
begin
  For i in (select object_type, object_name from user_objects o
            where object_name != 'ZRETAIN_LIST' and object_type in ('TABLE', 'FUNCTION', 'PROCEDURE', 'PACKAGE', 'SEQUENCE' )
            and not exists ( select 1 from zretain_list where tab_name = o.object_name ) )
  loop
    execute immediate 'drop '||i.object_type || ' ' || i.object_name ;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the answer, running you code is giving me following errors: I am not guru can you please help :-)SQL> @lop.sql
    execute immediate 'drop '||i.object_type || ' ' || object_name ;
                                                       *
ERROR at line 6:
ORA-06550: line 6, column 56:
PLS-00201: identifier 'OBJECT_NAME' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 6, column 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: Thanks. Working like a charm